# Angular2 @ngrx Store ok but observable type confuses me

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

Trying to make this [Angular + ngrx store boiler](https://github.com/LucasFrecia/angular2-ngrx-boiler) personal project boilerplate work but getting a typings error. The error message is quite straight forward but I cannot work around it without changing the type of the observable. First, here goes the error when running `npm start`

```
app/app.component.ts(29,9): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number[]>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Line 29 is inside the constructor and is:

```
constructor(    
    private store: Store<AppState>
){
    this.counter$ = store.select('counter');  // Line 29
}
```

In the code, if I change the following observable type from:

```
counter$: Observable<number>;
```

To:

```
counter$: Observable<any>;
```

`npm start` runs like a charm there, but I want to know why since I am trying to force a number type on the Obserbable

EDIT: add reducer code:

```
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';

export const counterReducer: ActionReducer<number> = (state: number = 0, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return state + 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix for this would be to  add the generic to the select aka map operator on store  like so

```
this.counter$ = store.select<number>('counter');  // Line 29
```

I think what is happening is that when you do the select in the manner you do then TypeScript cannot infer the type.

Another way to do this so it can infer type is to do the selector like so.

```
this.counter$ = store.select(state$ => state$.counter);  // Line 29
```

The second will pass in the state object and you can select the specific reducer from it.  I'm not positive but I think it should be able to infer the type this way.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code it is hard to know exactly what is happening, but it seems like your `store.select('counter')` is returning an observable of an object, where you type `counter$` as an observable of a number. When you use `store.select('reducerName')`, store will return to you an observable of the last value that was returned from your reducer function. If you are initializing your state to an empty object, for example

`export const counter = (state = {}, action) => {`

that could lead to the error you are seeing, and you could instead try initializing your state to the type that your observable is expecting.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, pasted reducer code. Still can´t quite get what is breaking here